# coloring <tr> based on value in <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-color

I need to color the table row based on the value in table division .
consider the below table

```
<table bgcolor="#FF0000">
  <tr>
  <td>90%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>80%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>50%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want the first row to be 90% colored , second will be 80% and the 3rd will be 50%.
How to achieve this .
Thanks

Comment: set the id for tr and set the color for every row...

Comment: I dont want to color the complete tr but only part of it according to the value in td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('table').find('td').each(function(){
   $(this).parent().css( {"width":$(this).html(),"float":"left","background-color":'#000'});
});
```

Comment: Hi Sachin , Thanks ... I tried this but the output is not proper . maybe i am doing a mistake in applying it .If possible can you provide a fiddle .

Comment: thanks :) I will accept your answer . can you tell me how I can make the background white ? I mean i dnt need the border . it should just show the color . Exactly similar to answers.atlassian.com/leaderboard

Comment: @sachin : try setting the value to 01% or something similar , the table breaks

Comment: @Mizan add 'clear:left' style to the table row.it will solves the pbm.

Comment: @Mizan still u have any pbm..let me know

Answer (score 2):

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    var opac = $(this).children().text();
    $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(255, 255,10," + opac + ")");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wQccw/

Comment: Hi Darren , Thanks for providing the fiddle .. can we set the color width also ? I mean the row shold only be 90% or 80% or n% colored . similar to https://answers.atlassian.com/leaderboard/

Comment: @Mizan - this is a new question.  You should accept an answer here and then ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You must take the value of the td cell like that `$('tr').children().html();`

It will return string which you can use to set opacity
 `$('tr').children().css('opacity', newvalue)`

You decide how to use it. The returned string will be like "80%" you can strip the first char and parse it to integer or just use SWICH CASE (on 80% set the opacity:0.8 and so on...)

Comment: thanks , this will set the opacity but i need to display the color as progress in the tr .. I need similar to this https://answers.atlassian.com/leaderboard/

Comment: Now I get exactly what you need, check @sachin answer, it does exactly that - you're changing the width of the td (which is with solid color)